# The method clone() from the type Object is not visible - Answers given confuse me

Tags: java, clone

I know this question has been asked before, but everyone seems to give the same answer, put this:

```
 public Object clone(){  
 try{  
     return super.clone();  
 }catch(Exception e){ 
     return null; 
 }
}
```

into the class and add `implements Cloneable` to the class label and it should work. But it doesn't work in the case I am trying. My code is:

```
            while (it.hasNext()) 
            {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                for(int i = 0; i < listOfString[k].size(); i++)
                {
                    String vals = listOfString[k].get(i);


                    if((vals).endsWith(pair.getValue().toString()))
                    {         

                        temp = vals.substring(0,29);
                        Object tempCopy = "";
                        tempCopy= temp.clone();

                        temp1[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(tempCopy.toString(),2);
                        System.out.println(temp1[j][i]);      // gives value if I use temp directly  - without cloning                   
                    }
                    temp ="";
                    System.out.println(temp1[j][i]); //gives 0 if i use temp directly - without cloning
                }
                j++;
                it.remove();
            }
```

Basically, I have a `map` with `<String, Int>` key value pairs and an `ArrayList` of `Strings`. The important part of this question is that I'm trying to put `integer` values into my `array` temp1. Since Java passes by reference and I don't want my `temp` string to get reset, I used the `.clone()` method. I still get the error in the title of this question inspite of doing what people have said. Also, in case someone has an answer on how to make sure that `temp1` does not lose values when I reset `temp` to `""`, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the type of `temp`? Let me guess: `Object`?

Comment: Even if `String` is passed "by reference" (in your terminology), it may be safely passed without copying or cloning, because `String` is immutable class. Same to `Integer`.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: *"Since Java passes by reference..."* No, it doesn't. Java is purely pass-by-value. The value in question when you're dealing with an object is an *object reference*, but that has nothing to do with pass-by-reference, which is a term of art referring to passing references **to variables** (not objects) into methods. Specifically in regard to strings, since strings are immutable (barring hacks), you never need to worry about passing strings into methods, there's nothing the method can do (non-maliciously) that will modify the string.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou if I use `System.out.println(temp[j][i])` after temp = ""; I get only 0s which is not right.

Comment: @T.J Crowder - see my response to Sasha Salauyou. Why does this happen then?

Comment: @TusharSharma this happens because `tempCopy` is "" (as you said, `clone()` "doesn't work").

Comment: @TusharSharma what I try make you to understand: `String` instances **does not** need to be cloned. They can be passed safely in any methods, because `String` is immutable--you cannot change its value.

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou I don't understand. I mean using clone() is giving me the error mentioned at the title. Why is that?

Comment: String(s) are immutable so you should never need to clone them

Comment: @TusharSharma because `String` **does not** implement `Clonable`, such **does not** override `clone()` method.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou implementing the interface is not enough, the method also has to be public, which it isn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey oh, sure, I forgot that is a very uncommon interface. Fortunately, used rarely nowadays.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Okay, then why does my second `System.out.println` give me 0 while the first one doesn't? Can you please answer that - what I mean is, if I don't use clone and just send `temp` to `temp1 = Integer.parseint();` then the commentss apply

Comment: @TusharSharma without seeing your inputs there is no way to confirm the code is doing what you think it is doing. I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see why it is doing something you don't expect.

Comment: @TusharSharma most of the time when the code appears to be doing something which doesn't make sense its because it is not doing what we think it is doing. i.e. how do you know which is the first and which is the second? How do you know one line is inside the `if` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Object.clone() was added in Java 1.0 and like some of the earliest decisions, they might have been done differently today.

Object shouldn't have a **protected** method called clone IMHO, but Cloneable should have such a public method.  Today, this might be done using a default method to a utility class to clone the object but that wasn't an option back then.

The downside of the current implementation is that all Object have protected clone() even those which don't support it.  In the case of String, like all immutable classes, it doesn't make sense to clone the object so it is not public, but really, ideally, it shouldn't be there at all.